# Help with flex widgets

Tags: apache-flex

I want to create two widgets in flex. One for the movies ( that would display the latest movies out, and where they are being showed on the bases of city)

and another widget for stocks.

does anyone know where can i find this information. and how can i make this. 
Or if you know about an open source flex that would be helpful in this, that would be even better.

Regards
Zee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FREE historical stock quotes (open, high, low, close, ...) you can get it from Yahoo Finance as a csv file and then parse that.  To get intraday values you need to sign up for the TDAmeritrade API (there may be other ways).  I've build products using both and Yahoo would be the simpler of the 2.